# How to loop within a loop in R?

Tags: r, loops, igraph, purrr

There are several similar questions on SO to this but I can't find an exact match for what I'm looking for.

I'd like to set some vertex attributes for a list of graphs, using `igraph's` `set_vertex_attr` function.  I'd like to have all variables in a `split` `data_frame` as the attributes and use the variable names as vertex attribute names.  My approach is to use a loop within a loop, but this is too advanced for me and I've hit a roadblock.  Here is my code:

```
library(tidyverse) #to keep it tidy
library(igraph) #for graphs

list_graphs <- list(graph.star(5),
                    graph.star(5),
                    graph.star(5))

df <- data_frame(name = c(rep('one',5),
                                rep('two',5),
                                rep('three',5)),
           x_vary = sample(1:1000,15),
           y_vary = sample(1:1000,15))

ls_dfs <- split(df,f= df$name)

for(i in seq_along(list_graphs)){
  for(j in seq_along(ls_dfs)){

     set_vertex_attr(graph = list_graphs[[i]],
                name = names(df[i]),
                value = ls_dfs[[i]][[j]])

  }
}
```

The output I'm looking for is for each graph in `list_graphs` to have the following vertex attribute names and attributes sourced from the `data_frame`.

Comment: Where have you defined `list_df`? That has been used in `name = names(list_df[i],` line.

Comment: Sorry, that should be `name = names(df[i]),` I've fixed it now.

Comment: Also, since `j` is `seq_along(ls_dfs)`, seems like your last line has `i` and `j` switched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this might be what you need

```
map2(list_graphs, ls_dfs, function(g, attr) {vertex_attr(g)<- attr; g})
```

We use `map2` from the tidyverse to walk over the `list_graphs` and `ls_dfs` together. This does assume that the sequence in each match up. Note that in your example you have `names(ls_dfs ) == c("one", "three", "two")` which might not be the order you expect.

But then we just use `vertex_attr<-` to set all the attributes at once by assigning the data.frame since a data.frame is really just a named list.

Comment: I'm confused about how the `attr` object fits in?

`map(list_graphs,get.vertex.attribute)` returns a `NULL` list.

Comment: `walk2` grabs the first item from `list_graphs` and the first from `ls_dfs` and passes those into the function. I just happened to call those parameters `g` and `attr`. I could have called them anything. Then `walk2` to will do the same with the second element from each of the lists and so on.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.  Did it work for you? The list of graphs isn't showing any new attributes. Thanks.

Comment: @elliot. I changed it to `map2` which will return a new, updated list. I forgot that `vertex_attr` doesn't modify by reference but returns a new object.

Comment: that works perfectly. Thanks, you are a legend among men.